# Getting one input field to take two entered values and perform Math.pow()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript / jQuery calculator with a button which performs the mathematical operation of raising the first entered integer to the second entered integer via the function:

```
$('#button-power').click(function(form){
var base = this.form.display.value; // the 1st value entered by user

setTimeout (function(){
      $("#disp").val('0'); // resets the calc display to 0 to accept second argument
    },0.5);

$("#button-enter").click(function(form){ // the 'equals' button
    var exponent = this.form.display.value; // the 2nd value entered by user
    var result = Math.pow(base,exponent);

setTimeout (function (form){
      $('#disp').val(result);
    },1);
    });

});
```

where `#disp` is the calculator display. The function works fine and produces the correct answer, but it causes other buttons on the calculator to behave incorrectly after a calculation is performed using the power button. I know this has something to do with the fact that the function requires two values as other calculator buttons that require two inputs (one which performs permutation calculations, for example) exhibit similar behavior. Trying to divide 8 by 2 after performing a power function will return something off the wall like 35 for instance.

Relevant functions which may be contributing to this behavior include:

```
function checkNum(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var ch = str.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (ch < "0" || ch > "9") {
      if (ch != "/" && ch != "*" && ch != "+" && ch != "-" && ch != "." && ch != "(" && ch != ")" && ch != "%") {
      $('#disp').val("Error");
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  return true
}

function addChar(input, character) {
  if (input.value == null || input.value == "0"){
    input.value = character}
  else{
    input.value += character}
};

$.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], function(i, e) {
  $('#button-' + e).click(function() {
  if ($('#disp').hasClass("result")) {
      $('#disp').removeClass("result").val("");
    }
    addChar(this.form.display, e);
  });
});
```

Other buttons on the calculator that require just one input, like the cosine button for example, utilize JavaScript and jQuery in this way:

```
function cos(form) {
    form.display.value = Math.cos(form.display.value);
}

$('#button-cos').click(function() {
  if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
    cos(this.form);
    $('#disp').addClass("result");
  }
});
```

I am wondering if it is possible to get the calculator to display something like `2^5` and parse this somehow to perform `Math.pow(2,5)`? I think this will solve the problem.

Here's a fiddle of the calculator: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh2x7vja/819/

Apologies for the messy script - I have yet to clean it up!

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?, create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: you can split a string with the carat "^" character and then raise the number at the 0 index by the power of the number in the 1st index.